# How to resize titlebar buttons?

Tags: gtk, theme, gtk3

I am trying to resize the close, minimize, maximize buttons. I do it like this:

```
.titlebar.default-decoration button.titlebutton {
  min-height: 36px;
  min-width: 36px;
  -gtk-icon-transform: scale(1.5);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This makes button icons become blurry for some reason:

[image: img]

For comparison, here is how they look without `-gtk-icon-transform: scale(1.5)`:

[image: img]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved. Add this code to your `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```css
button.titlebutton {
    min-height: 32px;
    min-width: 32px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This will increase title buttons size for all GTK applications including Firefox. It's actually what I need.